# Where does Cuda kernel code reside on nvidia GPU?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have gone through [Cuda programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) but still not clear where does cuda kernel reside on GPU? In other words, in which memory segment does it reside?

Also, How do I know what is the max kernel size supported by my device? Whether max kernel size depend on number of simultaneous kernels loaded on device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions are stored in global memory that is inaccessible to the user but are prefetched into an instruction cache during execution.

The maximum kernel size is stated in the Programming Guide in section G.1: 2 million instructions.

Comment: Just to be clear, are there restrictions if two kernels together exceed 2 million instructions? eg can they be executed concurrently?

Comment: That, I don't know, but I doubt it. Personally, I think that if you're getting up to the instruction limit, you should rethink your kernel design to be a bit more modular.